# Как прочитать файл,

Tags: java

как прочитать файл txt в java?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Что Вы пытались сделать? что именно не получается?

Comment: Почему перед тем как задать вопрос вы не воспользовались поиском на данном ресурсе? Ваша проблема уникальна?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Вот пример построчного чтения:***

```
private static final String FILENAME = "E:\\test\\filename.txt";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME))) {

        String sCurrentLine;

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```